# Pygame: How to tile subsurfaces on an image

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame

I'm completely new to Python/Pygame and I'm trying to slice an image up into subsurfaces and then blit them in order to the screen (so that later on I can modify it to call upon a certain tile and then blit it).

E1: I think I've finally managed to slice it the right way but there's a little hitch with the blitting.
E2: Updated the code and error (been getting this one on most of the code I tried before as well).

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen.fill((255, 255, 255))


def load_tileset(filename, width, height):
    image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
    image_width, image_height = image.get_size()
    tileset = []
    for tile_x in range(0, image_width//width):
        line = []
            tileset.append(line)
        for tile_y in range(0, image_height//height):
            rect = (tile_x*width, tile_y*height, width, height)
            line.append(image.subsurface(rect))
    return tileset

def draw_background(screen, tile_img, field_rect):
    img_rect = tile_img.get_rect()

    for y in range(0,400,32):
        for x in range(0,600,32):
            screen.blit(tile_img, (x,y))


Field_Rect = Rect(50,50, 300,300)
tileset = load_tileset("platform1.bmp", 17, 17)    
bg_tile_img = tileset[0]
draw_background(screen, bg_tile_img, Field_Rect)    

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()

    pygame.display.flip()
```

The error it gives atm is:
img_rect = tile_img.get_rect()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_rect'

Comment: Show the code you have tried and exactly what errors you get or how it is not working.

Comment: I've tried about 20 different ways, I don't have the code of all of them anymore however the error that comes up 80% of the time is an out of bounds thing. That the subsurface rectangle is outside the surface bounds. Eventhough the math says it isn't. =/

Comment: I'm afraid you won't get any help with this question if you don't show what you have done. Show your best of the 20 efforts and exactly how it fails.

Comment: Added the code that was working best, found some mistakes and managed to correct them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function here where you create the tileset:

```
def load_tileset(filename, width, height):
    image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
    image_width, image_height = image.get_size()
    tileset = []
    for tile_x in range(0, image_width//width):
        line = []
            tileset.append(line)
        for tile_y in range(0, image_height//height):
            rect = (tile_x*width, tile_y*height, width, height)
            line.append(image.subsurface(rect))
    return tileset
```

...you will notice that `tileset` is a list, and each element of tileset (labeled as `line`), is also a list.

So in this code here:

```
tileset = load_tileset("platform1.bmp", 17, 17)    
bg_tile_img = tileset[0]
draw_background(screen, bg_tile_img, Field_Rect)
```

...you are passing a list, called `bg_tile_img`, to the `draw_background` function.

Your `draw_background` function should instead look more like this:

```
def draw_background(screen, tile_img, field_rect):
    for img in tile_img:
        img_rect = img.get_rect()

        for y in range(0,400,32):
            for x in range(0,600,32):
                screen.blit(img, (x,y))
```

Alternatively, instead of passing `bg_tile_img` as a list, pop an element off of it to pass to the `draw_background` function.

Comment: Yup that did fix it, it doesn't entirely work like I intended but it works nevertheless and a simple renaming of some variables will make things a lot clearer. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the tileset:

```
load_tileset("platform1.bmp", 17, 17)
```

should be:

```
tileset = load_tileset("platform1.bmp", 17, 17)
```

**Update:**

`set_mode` creates the window, so it should be outside the main loop (load_tileset too):

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
tileset = load_tileset("platform1.bmp", 17, 17)

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...
```

Also, I can't see any call to `draw_background`.

**Update2:**

As Haz said, tileset is a list of lines (a matrix), you could use coordinates to retrieve a specific tile:

```
bg_tile_img = tileset[0][0]
```

Or make the tileset a plain list, adding everything directly to the tileset instead of using lines.

Comment: Doing this just gives me an active blank window. It's doing something but it's not giving me any output nor errors. As far as I can see it keeps recreating the window for some bizarre reason.

Comment: Updated the code again. I don't understand why it's using the bg_tile_img as a list object rather than what the object actually contains. =/